# How to solve the first order ODE by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

There is a first-order ODE

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{a(\ln\frac{1-c}{1-y})^3}{\frac{b-y}{1-y}+\ln\frac{1-c}{1-y}},$$
which is subjected to the initial condition $y(t=0)=y_0$ with $a,b,c$ are all constants. I do know it is hardly to get an explicit expression for $y(t)$. Even so, it should be solvable with the method of separation of variables for an implicit result for $y(t)$, which might include the logarithmic integral function

$$li(x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}.$$
Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this will help, I find the $li$ integral here: $$\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{\ln^2 \frac{1-c}{1-y}}+\frac{1}{a}\frac{\frac{b-y}{1-y}}{\ln \frac{1-c}{1-y}}$$ let $s=\frac{1-c}{1-y}$, it is $$\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{dt}{ds}\frac{ds}{dy}=\frac{dt}{ds}\frac{1-c}{(1-y)^2}=\frac{1}{a}\ln ^{-2}s + \frac{1}{a}\frac{b-y}{(1-y)\ln ^3 s}$$ let $r=\frac{1}{s},1-y=(1-c)r$ so $$\frac{dt}{dr}=-\frac{1-c}{a  \ln ^2 r}+\frac{1-c}{a  \ln ^3 r}+\frac{b+1}{a r \ln ^3 r}$$ the last terms is like $\frac{d \ln ^{-2} y}{dy}$, and the 2nd term can use integral by part to turn to the first one, and use integral by part also change the first one to the the $li$ integral, so let $$T=t-\frac{(1-c)r}{2a\ln r}+\frac{(1-c)r}{2a\ln ^2 r}+\frac{b+1}{2a \ln^2 r}$$ it is $$\frac{dT}{dr}=-\frac{1-c}{2a}\frac{1}{\ln r}$$ and the $li$ function can be found here. Thanks to @lxy to find my mistake :)

Comment: Hi @ Alexis, your idea is great! However, I doubt there might be a redundant $\frac{1}{r}$ in each right-hand term of the expression of $\frac{dt}{dr}$.

Comment: Hi @lxy, I checked again, I think it is $$\frac{dt}{dr}\frac{dr}{ds}\frac{ds}{dy}=-\frac{1}{s^2}\frac{1}{1-y}\frac{dt}{dr}=-\frac{r^2}{(1-c)r}\frac{dt}{dr}$$ so, there will be $\frac{1}{r}$ r.h.s.

Comment: @ Alexis, thanks for your patience. Based on your transformation $s=\frac{1-c}{1-y}$, $\frac{ds}{dy}=\frac{1}{r(1-y)}$. So there should be a missed $\frac{1}{r}$ in the first equality of you above reply. Thus, there is no $r$ in the second equality. Am I right :)

Comment: @lxy Yes I see! I am wrong, sorry! So it is the first 2 terms that will have $li$, sorry.

Comment: Hi @ Alexis, could you please revise your answer, then let me accept it :). Because I think your logic is beautiful, which is an inverse-function ideology for separating variables actually. Otherwise it is hardly to separate variables in the form of original function! Without your revision, it is hard for someone else to understand your method well. Thank your again for your input!

Comment: @lxy Thanks for finding my mistake!

Comment: @ Alexis. Although I accept your answer. But there are still some mistakes in the expression of $\frac{dt}{dr}$. According to my derivation, $\frac{dt}{dr}=-\frac{1-c}{a\ln^2r}+\frac{1-c}{a\ln^3r}+\frac{b-1}{ar\ln^3r}$.

Comment: @lxy yes you right, I fixed it, thanks again

Comment: Hi @ Alexis. That is very kind of you!  1. The last term of $\frac{dt}{dr}$ should be like $\frac{d(\ln^{-2} y)}{dy}$ instead of $\frac{d(\ln^{-1} y)}{dy}$; 2. I still can not understand how you link $t$ to $T$. Could you add a somewhat more detailed step for transforming the 2nd term on r.h.s. of $\frac{dt}{dr}$ to the first term.

Comment: @lxy , thanks again for point out that, I fix it, too. About the relation of $T$ and $t$, it is nothing interesting but a symbolic way to say that I have integral $\frac{1}{r \ln ^3 r}$, and use integral by part on $\frac{1}{\ln ^3 r}$ and $\frac{1}{\ln ^2 r}$, I think it is a simpler way to establish so I think I will leave it like that. The detail relation between 2nd term and first term is $$d(\frac{r}{2\ln ^2 r})=\frac{1}{2\ln ^2 r}dr-\frac{1}{\ln ^3 r}dr$$

Comment: @ Alexis, Thanks again! Now, the most puzzled thing is what is your mean by "use integral by part change the first term to the $li$ integral"? The integrating by part for the first term is $$\frac{1}{\ln^2r}dr=d(\frac{r}{\ln^2r})+\frac{2}{\ln^3r}dr$$. However, I can not link them to $li$ integral. Sorry for the stupid question, if it is the case.

Comment: Hi @lxy $$\frac{1}{\ln ^2} dr = - r \times (- \frac{1}{r\ln ^2 r})dr=-r d\frac{1}{\ln r}= - d (\frac{r}{\ln r})+\frac{1}{\ln r}dr$$