# Seeking a closed form solution to an ODE, if any.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I am try to solve the following ODE by the method of separation of variables.

$$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{b}{x\left\{\ln^3 x+\ln x[c+d(ax+b)][2\ln x+c+d(ax+b)] \right\}},$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are constants. I think it could contain a special function, say, the logarithmic integral function
$$li x=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\ln t}.$$
After several days' effort, I still can not get the solution. Thus, I seek some help or hint here. There is a [related topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491908/how-to-solve-the-first-order-ode-by-separation-of-variables) posted by me previously.

Comment: If I may ask, where did you find such a monster ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks for your concern :) It is actually a part of my model of a dynamical system.

Comment: Did you try numerical integration of the ODE ? I am curious to know how could look $F(x)$ for any set of constants of your choice.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici The numerical integration for this ODE should be somewhat easier than solve it by pencil and paper :), say first use power series to expand it in $\ln x$, or, linearize the RHS around a fixed point...just mention for discussion. However, at this stage I am more interested in the **analytical** solution :)